# Extract Multiple Attr from Image title atrib (playlist)

Tags: jquery, attributes, title, attr

**I have this code:** (Normal)

```
<div class="thumbInnerContainer">
    <div class="thumbs">
       <img src="/uploads/2012/09/image1.jpeg" class="thumb_img" title="Image Title description 1"> 
    </div>

    <div class="thumbs">
       <img src="/uploads/2012/09/image2.jpeg" class="thumb_img" title="Image Title description 2"> 
    </div>

    <div class="thumbs">
       <img src="/uploads/2012/09/image3.jpeg" class="thumb_img" title="Image Title description 3"> 
    </div>
</div>
```

**So, I want to Extract the TITLE attr from images** (see sample below)

```
<div class="titles">Image description 1</div>
<div class="titles">Image description 2</div>
<div class="titles">Image description 3</div>
```

I want use jQuery. How can I do this?

**remember that's multiple images. I found a solution, but this is only a picture and not multimple.**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will go through each image with a title attribute and add the title to a div with the `id` `titlesContainer`:

**Javascript**

```
$('img[title]').each(function() {
    $('#titlesContainer').append('<div class="titles">' + $(this).attr('title') + '</div>');
});
```

**HTML**

```
<div id="titlesContainer"></div>
```

**[Demo](http://jsbin.com/ulimer/1/edit/)**

Comment: zOMG! Exacly, thanks you very very very much ;) now I'm going to try. best regards.